# Filling DropDownList with JSonResult data only returns "undefinded"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net MVC 5 project I am trying to do a cascading DropDownList using AJAX. The JSON result action seems to be working and the jQuery code also seems to work the only problem is that the DropDownList is filled with "undefined".

JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult GetSectionGeographyTypes(Int16 SectionID)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GeographyTypes;

        using (GeographyContext db = new GeographyContext())
        {
            GeographyTypes = new SelectList(db.GeographyTypes.Where(gt => gt.SectionID == SectionID), "ID", "Name").ToList();
        }

        return Json(new SelectList(GeographyTypes), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        throw new HttpException(500, "Error processing request.");
    }
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetSectionGeographyTypes")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { SectionID: $( "#Section" ).val() },

    success: function ( GeographyTypes )
    {
        $.each( GeographyTypes, function ( i, Type )
        {
            $( "#GeographyType" ).append( '<option value="' + Type.ID + '">' + Type.Name + '</option>' );
        } );
    },
    error: function ( xhr, err )
    {
        alert( "readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status );
        alert( "responseText: " + xhr.responseText );
    }
} );
```

I have tested directly filling the DropDownList directly with the query and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
public class GeographyType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, Index("IX_Geography_Type", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Index("IX_Geography_Type", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show the json response which returned by action?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am not sure how to do that in MVC, I am really new to it.

Comment: you can use firebug for firefox to check what is the json response returned by ajax call or use chrome dev tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 
this line:

```
$( "#GeographyType" ).append( '<option value="' + Type.ID + '">' + Type.Name + '</option>' );
```

with this one:

```
$( "#GeographyType" ).append( '<option value="' + Type.Value + '">' + Type.Text + '</option>' );
```

You are returning `SelectList`: which is a list of `SelectListItem` - the don't have id and name properties, only `text` and `value` properties

**Explanation as sugested by @Ehsan Sajjad:**

The flowing line:

```
 new SelectList(db.GeographyTypes.Where(gt => gt.SectionID == SectionID), "ID", "Name")
```

Initializes a new instance of the `SelectList` class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, and the data text field. Which means in this case that `GeographyType.ID` will be mapped to `SelectListItem.Value` and `GeographyType.Name` will be mapped to `SelectListItem.Text`. So in this case on client side you can access only `Value` and `Text` properties. if you want to access the by other names you shouldn't be using `SelectList`.

For accessing the properties as you tried in your code you should do the following:

```
    var geographyTypes = db.GeographyTypes.Where(gt => gt.SectionID == SectionID).Select(x=> new
    {
      ID = x.ID,
      Name = x.Name
    }).ToList();

return Json(geographyTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Check the latest answer

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete `SelectList` maps the `Id`and `Name` of your type to `Value` and `Text` if you want to use your own type properties then you don't need to make a `SelectList`

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad i hope that the explanation is clear enough - Thanks for the suggestion.